# Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient Issues

Tags: api, zend-framework, frameworks, youtube

I am working on a project using the Youtube APIv2.

I am using the API through Zend Framework via Zend Gdata.

My application is querying the youtube api, getting a video feed then for each entry getting the name, thumbs, views, duration and tags for each video entry.

As announced by Google (http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/video-tags-just-for-uploaders.html) now to get the video tags of each video entry the youtube api request as to be authenticated by the user that owns the videos on youtube in order to retrieve these video tags.

What i've done is simply adding a developer key and a httpClient object when I init the *Zend_Gdata_YouTube* object, like that :
`$developerKey = 'mydevkey';
$authenticationURL = 'https://www.google.com/youtube/accounts/ClientLogin';
$idApplication = 'my_app_id';
$idClient = null;
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
    $username = 'google_account_email',
    $password = 'google_account_pass',
    $service = 'youtube',
    $client = null,
    $source = 'my_app',
    $loginToken = null,
    $loginCaptcha = null,
    $authenticationURL);
$this->yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $idApplication, $idClient , $developerKey);
$this->yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);`

I tested this piece of code in my project locally inside Mamp Pro and it works perfectly fine, retreiving the video tags as it should be, meaning that the code works.

My problem starts when i wan to put my code on my production server, the *Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient* object is not working and keeps giving me the error code "*Authentication with Google failed. Reason: BadAuthentication*"

I checked if someone else was having my problem and i came to this article "http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/03/clientlogin-fail.html", but neither of the 4 scenarios are similar to my problems.

Could someone help me ? Does my production server is missing something in terms of modules or authorizations (i check it doesn't looks like it).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My script was working locally, but not in production.

Change your password for a new one and run your script in production first.